# Need an intuitive understanding of $O_p(\cdot)$-notation.

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-analysis

My questions are described at the bottom. The example is generalized alot and in reality $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are estimators of intra-day variance of stock-returns and converges towards the integrated variance $V$. Suppose that we have two sequences of random variables $X_n$, $Y_n$ that both converge to $X_n \overset{P}\rightarrow V$, $Y_n \overset{P}\rightarrow V$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$. Assume that $X_n$ have rate of convergence equal to $O_p(n^{-1/2})$ and $Y_n$ equal to $O_p(n^{-1/4})$. Furthermore, we can recover a CLT for both sequences:

$\sqrt{n} (X_n - V) \overset{d}\rightarrow MN(0,\Sigma_X)$

$n^{1/4} (Y_n - V) \overset{d}\rightarrow MN(0,\Sigma_Y)$

such that both have pivotal quantities:

$\frac{\sqrt{n} (X_n - V)}{\sqrt{\Sigma_X}}\overset{d}\rightarrow N(0,1)$

$\frac{n^{1/4} (Y_n - V)}{\sqrt{\Sigma_Y}}\overset{d}\rightarrow N(0,1)$.

1. In general my confusion lies with the "slower rate of convergence" for two sequences converging towards the same limit. What does this imply intuitively, if $n$ was amount of sample points?
2. In general, what does a "slower rate of convergence" imply for $Y_n$ as opposed to $X_n$? That it needs more sample points to converge towards a standard normal variable (under the pivotal quantities)?

Comment: How is $O_p(\cdot)$ defined?

Comment: @supinf The "Big O in probability" notation is a shortcut for stochastic boundedness. Taken from the wikipedia ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation)), the notation for $X_n = O_p(a_n)$ with $X_n$ being random variables and $a_n$ a set of constants, means that the value  $\frac{X_n}{a_n}$ is stochastically bounded. That is, for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists a finite $M>0$ and $N>0$ such that $\mathbb{P}(|\frac{X_n}{a_n}|>M)<\epsilon$ for all $n > N$.